# WebApi GraphQL md5 hash Primary Key Id

Tags: asp.net-web-api, graphql, .net-7.0

I have a WebApi targeting .net 6 using EF core 7.
My installed packaged are:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.AspNetCore" Version="12.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.Data.EntityFramework" Version="12.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

My DataModel for the objectType is: (cleaned up for simplicity)

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace Soly.Data {
    public class Profiles {

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; } = 0;

        public string? Guid {
            get {
                return this.Id.ToString();
                /*
                string salt = "Z1@#!Q";
                using(MD5 md5 = MD5.Create()) {
                    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt + this.Id.ToString()));
                    return new Guid(hash);
                }*/
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When running the query:

```
query {
  profiles{
    Guid
  }
}
```

Now obviously Guid is returning back empty because the graphQL query does not request the Id field. My question is how can i append my request to always include the Id so that Guid populates.

I haven't seen anyone else trying to achieve this but essentially i am trying to protect the  Primary keys so that someone can't index my database.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem is with projection:
[IsProjected(true)]

This leads to the next issue, [GraphQLIgnore] not working with [IsProjected(true)]

My Final solution looks something like this:

```
public class SecurityIndexExt {
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        [GraphQLIgnore]
        private int realId;

        [Key]
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        //[GraphQLIgnore]
        [IsProjected(true)]
        public int Id {
            get {
                return 0;
            }
            set {
                this.realId = value;
            }
        }

        public Guid Guid {
            get {
                string salt = "Z1@#!Q";
                using(MD5 md5 = MD5.Create()) {
                    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt + this.realId.ToString()));
                    return new Guid(hash);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

ID is still available through GraphQL but it will only show 0.